# Spark scala: SELECT in a foreach loop returns java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I need to iterate over the contents of a DF with various SELECT statements inside a foreach loop, writing output to text files. Any SELECT statement inside the foreach loop returns a NullPointerException. I am unable to see why this is. A SELECT statement inside a "for" loop does not return this error.

This is the test case.

```
// step 1 of 6: create the table and load two rows
vc.sql(s"""CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEST1 (
 c1       varchar(4)
,username varchar(5)
,numeric integer) USING com.databricks.spark.csv OPTIONS (path "/tmp/test.txt")""")

// step 2 of 6: confirm that the data is queryable
vc.sql("SELECT * FROM TEST1").show()
+----+--------+-------+
|  c1|username|numeric|
+----+--------+-------+
|col1|   USER1|      0|
|col1|   USER2|      1|
+----+--------+-------+

// Step 3 of 6: create a dataframe for the table
var df=vc.sql("""SELECT * FROM TEST1""")


// step 4 of 6: create a second dataframe that we will use as a loop iterator
var df_usernames=vc.sql(s"""SELECT DISTINCT username FROM TEST1 """)

// step 5 of 6: first foreach loop works ok:
df_usernames.foreach(t => 
    {
      println("(The First foreach works ok: loop iterator t is " + t(0).toString() )
    }
)
(The First foreach works ok: loop iterator t is USER1
(The First foreach works ok: loop iterator t is USER2

// step 6 of 6: second foreach with any embedded SQL returns an error
df_usernames.foreach(t => 
    {
      println("(The second foreach dies: loop iterator t is " +     t(0).toString() )
      vc.sql("""SELECT c1 FROM TEST1""").show()
    }
)    
The second foreach dies: loop iterator t is USER1
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 158     in stage 94.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 158.0 in stage 94.0 (TID 3525, localhost): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.parseSql(SQLContext.scala:195)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't be done. You cannot start SQL query inside foreach without calling collect first

```
>>> df_usernames.collect.foreach(
... lambda x: sqlContext.sql("""SELECT c1 FROM TEST1""").show())
```

Comment: This is not the same foreach thought as the one the OP was using and it's not a good practice to collect without knowing the cardinality and the size of the data. It won't scale if you have lets say 2M users per example.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without using collect? For each "row" in the RDD, I need to compare with the existing data (which I can load in from SparkSession.sql).

Comment: I have faced the same thing and my understanding is this is difficult in SPARK and not a typical Use Case. Using the collect does work